# Can I travel to the Republic of Ireland from the UK without a passport?

Tags: passports, uk-citizens, ireland

I've searched on the net, and I'm getting mixed answers. Some sites saying *"You don't need a passport, a form of identification (ie: driving license) is fine"*, and others saying *"You need a passport"*.

I'm living in England (south west) and I wish to travel to Dublin (Ireland) in 2 weeks time. I've realised my passport is out of date and most likely I won't get an updated/renewed one before November 11<sup>th</sup> - which is when I am to travel to Dublin.

- To travel by air, would I need a valid passport or would another form of identification be fine?
- To travel by sea, would that be the same answer as to travel by air?

My confusion comes from Brexit (the UK coming out of Europe).

Comment: @pnuts I'm unable to find the links I found (the ones that are coming up now are old, and pre-brexit). Nationality is British. Going to travel on November 11th 2016

Comment: @pnuts Ah okay - so it's down to the airline on if I need a passport or not?

Comment: Ahh okay - would you be able to consolidate your comments into an answer that I can accept?

Comment: @pnuts but a driving license doesn't prove nationality.

Comment: you said "An official photo ID proving nationality issued to British nationals, arriving from Great Britain and Northern Ireland should be sufficient,". I'm struggling to think what such an ID could be (other than a passport), the ID card plan was scrapped and driving license don't prove nationality.

Comment: I took the ferry from Holyhead to Dublin and back last month and no one asked for ID in either direction, though I am aware they sometimes do and had my (Canadian) passport. I was disappointed since I no longer get UK entrance stamps and wanted to see if anyone would care. Flights to Dublin do pass through Irish immigration.

Comment: The UK is part of the EU and will likely remain that way for at least the next 2 years or so. While it's certainly useful to follow its progress, there is no need at this stage to worry about post-Brexit complications.

Comment: I used to work at what was the UK Passport Service (now Identity & Passport Service). You wouldn't believe how many people make mistakes on their passport application (usually not filling out the correct sections or missing documentation). While the 2-week "Check & Send" service from a post office will not be fast enough for you, it might be worth paying the fee for them to check your application before you go for a 1-week (or 1-day) renewal to avoid mistakes. Once you go into the building for your appointment, you won't be able to leave/return without re-booking.

Comment: Not ‘half of Ireland’ is part of the United Kingdom, but one-sixth of the *island of Ireland* is part of the UK. The remaining five sixths of the island form the *Republic of Ireland.* In your case, Dublin is the capital of the Republic of Ireland and hasn’t been part of the UK since 1922.

Comment: @PeterGreen A UK driving licence is accepted unquestioningly as sufficient in my experience.

Comment: @Basic HMPO makes mistakes as well.

Comment: @Calchas Unfortunately true... But better than nothing. The helpline is also pretty useful. They'll talk you through which sections and documents you need. Just trying to emphasise that it's important to get it right first time.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Yes, you can enter Ireland without a passport

Due to the [common travel area](http://www.citizensinformation.ie/en/moving_country/moving_abroad/freedom_of_movement_within_the_eu/common_travel_area_between_ireland_and_the_uk.html), both the [British government](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/ireland/entry-requirements) and the [Irish government](http://oireachtasdebates.oireachtas.ie/debates%20authoring/debateswebpack.nsf/takes/dail2012112700071?opendocument#WRU03250) affirm that you do not need a passport to travel between the UK and the Republic of Ireland.

## No, you cannot travel without a passport

However, almost all travel companies, by sea or by air, require photo identification. Travel by sea is usually a little more relaxed, and a driver's license (or other photo ID) should suffice. For flying, however, many airlines insist on seeing a passport. For example, [Ryanair](https://www.ryanair.com/gb/en/useful-info/help-centre/terms-and-conditions#section-termsandconditionsar_368204930-termsandconditionsse_579117795) (see Article 19) insists that you have a passport for international flights. (Other acceptable documents are national ID cards (which don't exist in the UK, unfortunately for you), UN Refugee Convention Travel Documents, and other standard exceptions.)

## The solution

Contact your airline. If they insist on a passport, then you can either 1) rebook your travel with a different carrier who do *not* insist on a passport (such as [Aer Lingus](https://www.aerlingus.com/travel-information/passports-and-visas/travel-to-from-britain/)), or 2) renew your passport using the [premium 1-day service](https://www.gov.uk/get-a-passport-urgently).

Comment: It's possible that an expired passport might be considered valid ID (not a travel document). I would ask before chancing it though.

Comment: Technically, only citizens of the UK and Ireland can travel between each other's countries without a passport, which might place you in the Catch-22 situation of having to produce your passport to prove that you don't need it. In practice this is unlikely to be a problem as long as you look and sound British or Irish.

Comment: @mikescott EEA nationals can travel freely between the two countries with only an ID card.

Comment: @DiegoSánchez true, but the UK doesn't issue ID cards. *Within* the UK, a photo driver's license is usually acceptable as proof of ID, or alternatively recent documents (less than 12 months old) showing your full name and address, from government organizations (e.g. related to income tax) or utility companies. But those alternatives probably won't be any use to the OP - "passport" means "passport"!

Comment: @MikeScott Upvote for the correct use of Catch-22.

Comment: @alephzero The implication was that citizens of *other* EEA nations than the UK or Ireland can also travel between both countries without a passport.

Comment: Why do you say "No, you cannot travel without a passport", when there are plenty of options for travelling without a passport?

Comment: Do you need a passport to get to Northernern Ireland? Because then you can just drive/take a bus.

Comment: The idea that "transport companies ... require photo identification" isn't true in my experience. I think I may have provided identity document details through online forms, but I've flown back and forth between mainland GB and Belfast a few times recently, and at no point have I had to show any photo ID.

Comment: No ferry company on the Irish Sea has ever asked me for any form of ID. Immigration at both Holyhead and Dublin have (there's never any emigration check). However, I was once let into Wales on the strength of a Bank of Ireland Visa Debit card with no photo on it.

Comment: @TRiG "there's never any emigration check" When I went by bus from London to Dublin, the UK Immigration Enforcement checked the passengers on Exit at Holyhead, but driving off the Ferry in Dublin there was no check

Answer (score 1):

You may be lucky and not need it, depending on your route and travel mode. But the safest is to travel with a passport, even if you are an Irish or UK citizen. A better-than-nothing option is to at least have a national ID card if you are an EU citizen as it's accepted in EU countries, including The Republic of Ireland, but the UK is no longer required or expected to accept it.

Note that the [Common Travel Area](https://www.citizensinformation.ie/en/government_in_ireland/ireland_and_the_uk/common_travel_area_between_ireland_and_the_uk.html) is intended for Irish and UK citizens:

> Common Travel Area rights can only be exercised by citizens of Ireland
> and the UK. If you are not a citizen of Ireland or the UK, you cannot
> exercise Common Travel Area rights.

For example, having a valid visa for the UK, technically does not mean that one can travel freely to Ireland. They also say:

> There are no routine passport controls in operation for Irish and UK
> citizens travelling between the 2 countries.
>
> However, you must show identification to board a ferry or an airplane,
> and some airlines and sea carriers only accept a passport as valid
> identification. You may also be asked by an immigration officer to
> prove that you are a citizen of Ireland or the UK, so you should carry
> a passport with you. You can also use an Irish passport card, or other
> proof that you are an Irish citizen.

In practice this means that if your form of identification is accepted for you to get on a plane from the UK to Ireland, and the plane takes you to a disembarking point where only travelers from the UK are expected, there may not be a border control at all. The reality of some airports is that sometimes travelers may be all lumped together from different flights, which means they all have go through passport control to enter the country.