# ID for UK to Ireland travel

Tags: passports, ireland, sea-travel, id

My partner and our children would like to book a crossing from UK to Ireland in the next few weeks.

I understand ID is required. I have not got a driving licence but I have an expired passport (13 of may 2015). I have my birth certificate and my old passport. Is this sufficient for ID? My partner has his driving license and I have birth certificates for our twins. They are under 2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/81977/can-i-travel-to-the-republic-of-ireland-from-the-uk-without-a-passport

Comment: Getting a provisional (learner) driving licence is easy but I am not sure that it is sufficient.  However, getting a passport is not much harder.  If you are flying, you might find that the airline is stricter than the immigration staff.

Comment: You could consider getting voting ID: https://www.electoralcommission.org.uk/i-am-a/voter/voter-id/applying-a-voter-authority-certificate

Answer (score 6):

No, an expired passport will not be acceptable.

Irish and British citizens do not strictly require a passport to travel between the two countries, but some form of (photo) identification is however required. The list of acceptable documents includes:

- Valid passport
- Photographic Driving License
- International Student Card
- Government issued photographic ID cards
- Health insurance/social security photographic ID cards
- Photographic bus/train pass
- Place of work photographic ID
- Birth certificates (for under 18’s with no photo ID)

Source: Irish Ferries https://www.irishferries.com/uk-en/frequently-asked-questions/top-10-faqs/passports-identification/